# How to remove double quotes from string binded in Angular?

Tags: html, css, angularjs

[image: Here what it looks like]
[image: In the inspector]

Here's the code

```
var app = angular.module('umovie-app');

app.directive('renamable', function($sce) {
return {
    scope: {
        model: '=model',
    },
    link: function(scope, elements, attributes) {
        var input = elements[0];

        scope.trustHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml(scope.model.name);

        $(input).click(function() {
            elements.addClass("active");
            $(input).html(`<input type="text" value="${scope.model.name}">`).unbind("click");
        });

        $(input).on('focusout', function() {});
    },
    template: '<a class="renamable">{{ trustHtml }} <i class="material-icons">mode_edit</i></a>',
};
});
```

Someone could tell me how to remove the double quotes generated by angular around my `trustHtml` variable when it is binded ?

Thank you !

EDIT: The result is like, I would like the icon aligned with my `<a></a>`

Comment: Is it actually showing quotation marks in your view? It looks like that's just an image from your browser's DOM inspector.

Comment: This is a screen shot of my browser's DOM

Comment: the double quotes from DOM's inspector are part of the inspector to show you that it is a shown text for the user. That does not indicate that they are visible quotes for the user. If so, you would be seeing double quotes inside the double quotes, like a double quote-ception

Comment: Okay ! So my problem is not the quotes, so why is there a new line after `{{ trustHtml }}` ?

Comment: Ohh, it's not a string ! It's an object !

Comment: Now it is a string but I still get a new line. My icon and my variable are not aligned

Comment: I tried `<a>Yoann Picquenot <i class="material-icons">mode_edit</i></a>` with raw value, there still the new line, so It's a html issue.

Comment: You need to use your DOM tools to find out why it is putting it on a separate line.  More than likely it is a CSS property, probably something to do with display attribute.  Which the text is being displayed as a block forcing the icon onto the next line

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem with a materialize class. This is in a navbar, and there is class to get an icon aligned with a button like :

`<a>Blablabl <i class="material-icon right">mode_edit</i></a>`

The `right` class is here to align the icon with the text.

Thank you for your help ! hope It will help someone in the future !